# How to send data from one API to another API using webclient

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, post, spring-webclient

I have two springboot microservices api_A running on localhost:8080 and api_B running on localhost:8081. How do I send data transfer object from api_A to api_B using webclient?

I have a `Person` class and I wanted to send this Object as json to api_B on endpoint localhost:8081/new-person.

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Person {
  String name;
  int age;
}
```

Currently, I have this class in api_A to send data to api_B when it starts.

```
public class Config {

@Autowired 
private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

@PostConstruct
public Mono<Person> send(){
WebClient webClient = webClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://localhost:8080").build();

Person person = Person.builder().build();

return webClient.post()
                .uri("/new-person")
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .body(Mono.just(person), Person.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Person.class);
}

}
```

I don't think this is working because whenever I go to localhost:8081/new-person I get an error.
Thank you !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080");

public Mono<Something> getSomething(int id) {
    webClient.get()
        .uri("uri", parameters)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Something.class);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Is this implemented on api_B? Thank you